# PHP Checking if something exists in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making an iOS app that sends a username string to this PHP file and then the PHP file checks to see if their username exists in a database, in a table called "members". I got this code online and modified it a little to fit my needs. This is the code:

```
// Main method to redeem a code
function redeem() {

    // Check for required parameters
    if (isset($_POST["username"])) {

        // Put parameters into local variables
        $code = $_POST["username"];

        echo $code;

        // Look up code in database
        $user_id = 0;

        echo "userid";

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username=', $code); 

        echo "dbprepare";

       $stmt->bind_param("is", $code);

        echo "bindparam";

        $stmt->execute();

        echo "execute";

        $stmt->bind_result($id, $code);

        echo "bindresult";

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            break;
        }
        $stmt->close();
```

The code is tripping up on `bind_param`, it only gets to `echo "dbprepare"`. Am I doing something incorrectly? How do I check for the username?

Comment: None of us have any idea what bind_param or bind_result mean.  What API / framework are you using?

Comment: +1 I think its not to be downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a `?` in your SQL.

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username=?', $code); 

echo "dbprepare";

$stmt->bind_param("is", $code);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
   $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username=?');  

    echo "dbprepare"; 

   $stmt->bind_param("s", $code);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would guess you do miss an actual placeholder here:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username=?', $code);
```

See the added `?`. The prepare call does not just append the value.
You do need to tell it where it belongs. (If your class implements prepare/bind as in mysqli or PDO, and as commonly understood.)

Comment: See also what Kashif wrote. If it's really mysqli, then you pass the variable separately, and with maybe just `'s'` as type specifier.